# ajax call in magento 2

Tags: ajax, magento, magento2

I have created a custom module in Magento2 where currently I'm selecting a customer and entered multiple order numbers, it will saved into a custom table in the database.

Currently I have to entered order numbers in a textarea but now I want to display all orders after choosing the customer which are not in Complete status.

From this section admin choose orders by clicking on the right side checkbox and Saved it.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

#### Existing Module’s Layout

[image: existing]

Want to modify the above layout to the following one: In this desired system when admin change the customer name order numbers associated with that customer will be listed.

#### New invoice

[image: new invoice]

Code I have used to create the customer dropdown field:

```
$fieldset->addField('customer_id', 'select', array(
    'label' => __('Customer'),
    'name' => 'customer_id',
    'title' => __('Customer'),
    'values' => $this->getCustomerOptionArray()
    ));

protected function getCustomerOptionArray()
{
    $options = array();

    $options[] = array(
        'value' => 0,
        'label' => __('Select Customer'),
        );

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();

    foreach ($customerObj as $customerObjdata ){
        $options[] = array(
            'value' => $customerObjdata->getId(),
            'label' => $customerObjdata->getName(),
            );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the screenshots and code were included in the question rather than a PDF in Google Drive. If that file is deleted from Drive, this question will become useless to future searchers. Additionally, without opening the PDF it's very unclear what you want answered. And finally, the title of the post doesn't do much to say what your question is actually about. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Clonkex - I've inlined the images and the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity Much better. Still not sure the questions is good enough for someone to answer, but at least it has the info there now.